# Vulnerability scanner inside AWS

Tags: network-scanners, nmap, amazon

I have three VPC's within AWS and I want to run an automated Nmap scan on all three VPC's every few weeks to make sure nothing has been opened, added, etc. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Make sure you submit a [Penetration Testing Request Form](http://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/) before you begin any testing, to ensure AWS knows that you are pen-testing your own servers.

Comment: When I asked to run nmap on my AWS VMs, Amazon denied my request because they were 'nano' VMs. Make sure you read the Terms of Service and what can and cannot be done.

Comment: m1.small and t1.micro will also get an automatic request denied according to the link @JohnDvorak submitted in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a network monitoring solution like [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/), [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.org/), [Observium](http://www.observium.org/), or [NeDi](http://www.nedi.ch/).

They will do more than just discover new systems and open ports.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're in VPC, I would recommend auditing your security group and network ACL configuration using a tool like Security Monkey: http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/06/announcing-security-monkey-aws-security.html

If you're interested in using nmap for this, it has a diff feature which may be of interest. I usually use a modified version of this script to scan my external space, as an out of band fail-safe in case change control is not followed, or someone has made an erroneous change. Sometimes people make assumptions about changes they've made which aren't acccurate, and this could catch an open port that you don't expect.  http://nmap.org/book/ndiff-man-periodic.html